# My array returns undefined when the dates do match, how do I make it fill with null instead?

Tags: javascript

I have made a script to check if the dates of an event match to dates on a calendar then return it as another array together.

However, the dates that do not have any events return as `undefined` I was wondering how could I make the search return a null or an empty object/array if nothing is found. The reason for this when I loop over the array it doesn't allow me to search for the found events because the first thing that is found is `undefined`.

```
      initialDays = initialDays.map((dates) => {
        return {
          date: format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          isCurrentMonth: isSameMonth(this.getNewDays, dates),
          isToday: isToday(dates),
          isSelected: isSameDay(dates, this.today),
          events: events.find((item) => {
            return item.datetime == format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
              })
        }
      })
```

This is what `events: events.find((item) => { return item.datetime == format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd')})` creates.
[image: What the function returns]

```
let events = [{ id: 1, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-10', href: '#' }, { id: 1, name: 'Date night', time: '8PM', datetime: '2022-10-10', href: '#' }, { id: 2, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-12', href: '#' }, { id: 3, name: 'Date night', time: '6PM', datetime: '2022-10-13', href: '#' }]
```

I have another function that creates dates from start of month to end of month that is what `dates` are.

Comment: `events: events.find((item) => { return item.datetime == format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}) ?? null`

Comment: I'd say, change `find` (which returns the first element), to `filter` (which returns an array of elements).

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thank you sir, it worked. I must read up about those operators... I just know && or the two lines hehe,

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Yeah I ran into the problem where if two events have the same day it just returns the first one.